# Question about how Strings Change each other in C

Tags: c, string

This is a followup to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982854/question-about-gzread-hexadecimal-and-bytes) I have asked before, but is different.  This is more about technical how C works.  So in the below code:

```
    char s[] = "#chromsize: chr1    249250621";
    char *p, *q, *chr;
    for (p = s + 11; isspace(*p) && *p != 0; ++p) {}
    assert(*p);
    printf("FLAG 1 (p): %s\n", p);
    for (q = p; *q != 0 && !isspace(*q); ++q) {}
    assert(*q);
    printf("FLAG 2 (p): %s\n", p);
    printf("FLAG 3 (q): %s\n", q);
    printf("FLAG 4 (q + 1): %s\n", q + 1);
    *q = 0;
    printf("FLAG 5 (q): %s\n", q);
    printf("FLAG 5.2 (p): %s\n", p);
    chr = p;
    p = q + 1;
    printf("FLAG 6 (q + 1): %s\n", q + 1);
```

And the output is

```
FLAG 1 (p): chr1    249250621
FLAG 2 (p): chr1    249250621
FLAG 3 (q):     249250621
FLAG 4 (q + 1): 249250621
FLAG 5 (q): 
FLAG 5.2 (p): chr1
FLAG 6 (q + 1): 249250621
```

So a few things confuse me.  First, you'll notice that `q+1` is the same before and after the line `*q = 0` (FLAG 4 and FLAG 6).  Why is this?  It seems to change `q` (based on FLAG 3 vs FLAG 5), but still `q+1` is the same.

Second, how does it work that after the line `*q = 0`, `p` goes from being equal to `chr1    249250621` to just `chr1` (FLAG 2, FLAG 5.2)?

Comment: `q+1 is the same before and after the line *q = 0`. If you change a byte at location `q` why would you expect that to affect the bytes from location `q+1` onwards? If you write a word on page 1 of your book and then you look at the contents on page 2 would you expect page 2 to have changed?

Comment: Could you please crystallize the code into a small essential example of what is confusing you? There are too much of unreadable and unrelated code.

Comment: Does `*q = 0` change the first element in the string array there to `0`, or the whole thing to `0`?  And `q+1` returns a string as well, right?  I guess that one makes more sense, the second one confuses me still though.  Also I condensed it down

Comment: `q` is a pointer to `char`. So any derference of it results in only a single char being read or written. Note functions like `printf` with `%s` are not reading just `q` but actually start from `q` and keep going until the end of the string which is denoted by a NUL terminator.

Comment: how does `q` go from `     249250621` to nothing (after `*q = 0`), and `q+1 = 249250621`?  It seems like the parts in `q+1` should still be downstream of `q`, and printed off with it.  Or does it not appear in the print because it starts with the null (which I think is what `0` is for here, right?)?

Comment: As I said, a string ends at the NUL character. so `*q=0` creates an empty string starting at `q`. Then there happens to be another string at `q+1`. So printing `q` gets an empty string and `q+1` gets the non-empty string after that. Basically, you are making two strings out of the original by adding a termination point somewhere in the middle of the original string.

Comment: Oh okay, so does the string pointed to by `p` change because the address `q` now points to a NUL.  That address is the same one downstream of `p`, so then now downstream of `p` is something like `chr1\0 249250621`, whereas it used to be just `chr1 249250621`? (So also splitting the string here into two)?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Thank you!  That's very cool... I'm still getting used to pointers, but they're use is always very interesting

Comment: The best way to understand this is to draw a diagram of the memory of `s` with each character in a numbered box. `p` and `q` then contain the appropriate box numbers. When you dereference one of them, it reads or writes into that box. And using the pointer as a string gets all the characters starting from that box to the first box containing `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding Question 1**:

In this situation we will have an array of chars somewhere in memory ("hello" in this example) and q knows at which address this array resides (eg 249250621 in your example)

This could look like:

```
q -----------.
             V
   +---+---+---+---+---+----+
   | h | e | l | l | o | \0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

So if we do a `*q = 0` we will set the value where q is pointing to ('l' in my example) So after this action, we will have:

```
q ------------.
              V
   +---+---+----+---+---+----+
   | h | e | \0 | l | o | \0 |
   +---+---+----+---+---+----+
              ^
              ^-- We just wrote a null-byte here.
```

Now take a closer look: Only the value inside the array changed. `q` itself has not changed. **It still points to the same memory location as it did before**. (This is your 249250621)

**For Question 2**:

q and p are pointing to the same char array. So as we changed the memory, this will also be visible for p. Lets re-use the example from above and add `p` to the mix:

```
q ------------.
              |
p ---.        |
     |        |
     V        V
   +---+---+----+---+---+----+
   | h | e | \0 | l | o | \0 |
   +---+---+----+---+---+----+
```

As you see, if we print the "thing" which `p` points to, we will not see the whole string anymore because it is zero-terminated now in middle.